# How to get an appended element to be the height of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am appending the div `.soonOverlay` to specific `.smallCatalogBlock`'s. What I can't seem to figure out is how I get the height of `soonOverlay` to be only as tall as the `img` in `smallCatalogBlock`. Right now its height covers the entire container.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or how I can fix this?

```js
$('.smallCatalogBlock').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('availability') === 'No') {
   $(this).append('<div class="soonOverlay"><div class="soonOverlayInner"><div class="total-center"><p class="dGw">Coming Soon</p></div></div></div>');
   console.log("It should be working");
  }
 });
```

```css
.smallCatalogWrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 60px 0;
}
.smallCatalogBlock {
 width: 60%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.smallCatalogBlock img {
 width: 80%;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 display: block;
 margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
}
.smallCatalogTitle {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.comingSoonSmall {
 position: relative;
}
.comingSoonSmall .soonOverlay {
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #b82222;
 opacity: .8;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0 10%;
}
.soonOverlayInner {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 350px;
}
.soonOverlayInner .dGw {
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-availability="No">
<img src="https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/puppy-dog.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782" alt="Fastening Technology Catalog">
  <span class="smallCatalogTitle">Technology</span>
  <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
    <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete How would I make this function work for the overlay though? I will use CSS or JS to fix this.

Comment: Why not wrap the image in it's own div and then append the overlay to that div then you can just position it absolutely with top bottom left right all set to 0

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the script below.

```js
$('.smallCatalogBlock').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('availability') === 'No') {
   $(this).append('<div class="soonOverlay"><div class="soonOverlayInner"><div class="total-center"><p class="dGw">Coming Soon</p></div></div></div>');
   console.log("It should be working");
      var img_w = $('.smallCatalogBlock > img').width();
      var img_h = $('.smallCatalogBlock > img').height();
      $('.soonOverlay').width(img_w).height(img_h);
  }
    
 });
```

```css
.smallCatalogWrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 60px 0;
}
.smallCatalogBlock {
 width: 60%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.smallCatalogBlock img {
 width: 80%;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 display: block;
 margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
}
.smallCatalogTitle {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.comingSoonSmall {
 position: relative;
}
.comingSoonSmall .soonOverlay {
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #b82222;
 opacity: .8;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0 10%;
}
.soonOverlayInner {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 350px;
}
.soonOverlayInner .dGw {
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-availability="No"> 
<img src="https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/puppy-dog.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782" alt="Fastening Technology Catalog"> 
<span class="smallCatalogTitle">Technology</span> 
<div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap"> 
<div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div> 
</div> 
</div>
```